# Azure Logic App - How can I re-started my operations failed?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-iot-hub

I have many operations failed in my Azure Logic App.
I see that if you click on a single operation on the Azure portal you can **re-started** the operation:

[image: Logic App]

Is it possible to select **ALL** of these failed operations, and re-run all together?
Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to resubmit one or more logic app runs that failed, succeeded, or are still running, you could bulk resubmit Logic Apps from the Runs Dashboard.

[image]

[image]

About how to use this function, you could refer to this article:[Monitor logic apps with Azure Monitor logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-monitor-your-logic-apps-oms). Under the tile [View logic app run information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-monitor-your-logic-apps-oms#view-logic-app-run-information), you could find the **Resubmit** description.

Comment: Perfect George it's perfect!. Unfortunately there isn't a **Select All** option in the Runs Dashboard, but it's ok. I hope Microsoft will develop that feature in the future! :)

Comment: To summarize the Microsoft documentation, the specific dashboard from George's screenshots can be accessed through associated Log Analytics workspace --> Workspace Summary --> Logic Apps Management (Runs) --> Logic App runs. From here, Logic Apps can be filtered and marked in bulk for resubmission.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to bulk resubmit Logic Apps from the Runs Dashboard, you can utilize the PowerShell commands. Take a look at the script below, which can automate  **listing Failed logic app runs**, **identify triggers**, **actions** responsible and **restart the apps** by input ResourceGroupName. *You can change some of those bits as per your needs.* *(skip the interactions and just restart apps again)* I have just show it for understanding.

> **Using:** Get-AzLogicApp, Get-AzLogicAppRunHistory ,
> Get-AzLogicAppRunAction, Get-AzLogicAppTrigger and Start-AzLogicApp
> cmdlets.

**Script using Az PowerShell 6.2 Module: Az.LogicApp** [Copy below to file, say restart.ps1 and run] Make sure you assign `$rg` with your actual `AzResourceGroup` name

```
$rg = "MyResourceGrp"

#get logic apps
$logicapps = Get-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName $rg

Write-Host "logicapps:" -ForegroundColor "Yellow" 
write-output $logicapps.Name

#list all logicapp runs failed
$failedruns = @(foreach($name in $logicapps.Name){

    Get-AzLogicAppRunHistory -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $name | Where {$_.Status -eq 'Failed'}
   
})

Write-Host "failedruns:" -ForegroundColor "Yellow" 
Write-Output $failedruns.Name | select -Unique
Write-Host "failedruns: LogicAppNames" -ForegroundColor "Yellow" 
Write-Output $failedruns.Workflow.Name | select -Unique

#list all logicappRunsActions failed

foreach($i in $logicapps){

    foreach($y in $failedruns){

        if ($i.Version -eq $y.Workflow.Name) {
            $resultsB = Get-AzLogicAppRunAction -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $i.Name -RunName $y.Name -FollowNextPageLink | Where {$_.Status -eq 'Failed'}
        }
    }
}


foreach($item in $resultsB){
    Write-Host "Action:" $item.Name " " -NoNewline "Time:" $item.EndTime 
    Write-Output " "
}


#get logicapp triggers

foreach($ii in $logicapps){

    foreach($yy in $failedruns){

        if ($ii.Version -eq $yy.Workflow.Name) {
            $triggers = Get-AzLogicAppTrigger -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $ii.Name
        }

    
    }
}

Write-Host "triggers:" -ForegroundColor "Yellow" 
Write-Output $triggers.Name

#start logic apps with triggers
Write-Host "Starting logic apps....." -ForegroundColor "green"

foreach($p in $logicapps){

    foreach($tri in $triggers){

        if ($p.Version -eq $triggers.Workflow.Name) {
            Start-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $p.Name -TriggerName $tri.Name
        }
    }
}


$verify = Read-Host "Verify ruuning app? y or n"

if ($verify -eq 'y') {

    $running = @(foreach($name2 in $logicapps.Name){

        Get-AzLogicAppRunHistory -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $name2 | Where {$_.Status -eq 'Running' -or $_.Status -eq 'Waiting'}
    })
    Write-Host $running
    
}

else {
    Write-Host "Bye!"
}
```

[image]

Although my `LogicApp` has failed again, but you can see it was triggered in time by script

[image]

[image]

**Note:** If your logic app trigger expects inputs or actions (unlike recurrence or scheduled) please edit or make changes accordingly for `Start-AzLogicApp` command to execute successfully.

Here I am considering all logic apps are enabled (use `-State Enabled`) parameter for `Get-AzLogicApp` command if you want to run this on only currently enabled apps.

Example: `Get-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName "rg" | where {$_.State -eq 'Enabled'}`

**2.** You can also try advanced settings for triggers in workflow. Such as retry policy.

[image]

You can specify it to retry at custom intervals in case of failures due to an intermittent issues.

[image]

You can [submit](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps) a feedback or Upvote a similar  [Feedback : ability-to-continue-from-a-particular-point-as-in](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/17884675-ability-to-continue-from-a-particular-point-as-in)

Refer: [help topics for the Logic Apps cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.logicapp/?view=azps-6.2.1#logic-apps)